# Discord.js: reaction.js event file not triggering

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am currently creating a reaction role event where people can interact with a message and get a role assigned to themselves after clicking a certain emoji, however for some reason the event will not trigger and no role is assigned to the user.

Below is my `reaction.js` event file:

```js
module.exports = async(reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
  if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
  if (user.bot) return;
  if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

  if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === 'pinkEmoji') {
      await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(pink);
    }
    if (reaction.emoji.name === 'yellowEmoji') {
      await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(yellow);
    }
    if (reaction.emoji.name === 'purpleEmoji') {
      await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(purple);
    }
  } else {
    return;
  }

  if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === 'pinkEmoji') {
      await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(pink);
    }
    if (reaction.emoji.name === 'yellowEmoji') {
      await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(yellow);
    }
    if (reaction.emoji.name === 'purpleEmoji') {
      await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(purple);
    }
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

I'm also using a command to let the bot know it has to send the message after typing in the command.

Here is my `reactionrole.js` command file if it helps:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'reactionrole',
  description: 'sets up a reaction role message!',
  permissions: ["MANAGE_ROLES"],
  cooldown: 10,
  async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord) {
    const channel = process.env.WELCOME;

    const pink = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Pink");
    const yellow = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Yellow");
    const purple = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Purple");

    const pinkEmoji = '';
    const yellowEmoji = '';
    const purpleEmoji = '';

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#e42643')
    .setTitle('Choose your own **Color Role**!')
    .setDescription('Choosing a color role will give you a coloured name!\n\n'
        + `${pinkEmoji} for pink color\n`
        + `${yellowEmoji} for yellow color\n`
        + `${purpleEmoji} for purple color`);
    
    let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
    messageEmbed.react(pinkEmoji);
    messageEmbed.react(yellowEmoji);
    messageEmbed.react(purpleEmoji);
  }
}
```

Below is the event handler I am using:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
  const load_dir = (dirs) => {
    const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for (const file of event_files) {
      const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
      const event_name = file.split('.')[0];
      client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client));
    }
  }
  ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
}
```

I have been stuck on this for quite a while now and I don't know where the problem lies because it's not throwing any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where or when the module from the `reaction.js` file is executed but if I check your event handler, it seems you want to listen to the `reaction` event. The problem is there is no `reaction` event. I think what you're looking for is the [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) event instead, so you should rename `reaction.js` to `messageReactionAdd.js`.

Still, roles like `pink`, `yellow`, etc. won't be available in this file if you're declaring them in `reactionrole.js`. You need to define them in this file instead.

```js
// messageReactionAdd.js
module.exports = async (reaction, user) => {
  if (user.bot) return;
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
  if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

  const channel = process.env.WELCOME;
  const { message } = reaction;
  const { guild } = message;

  if (!guild || message.channel.id !== channel) return;

  const pinkEmoji = '';
  const yellowEmoji = '';
  const purpleEmoji = '';

  const member = guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
  const pink = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'Pink');
  const yellow = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'Yellow');
  const purple = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === 'Purple');

  if (reaction.emoji.name === pinkEmoji) {
    await member.roles.add(pink);
  }
  if (reaction.emoji.name === yellowEmoji) {
    await member.roles.add(yellow);
  }
  if (reaction.emoji.name === purpleEmoji) {
    await member.roles.add(purple);
  }
};
```

```js
// reactionrole.js
module.exports = {
  name: 'reactionrole',
  description: 'sets up a reaction role message!',
  permissions: ['MANAGE_ROLES'],
  cooldown: 10,
  async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord) {
    const pinkEmoji = '';
    const yellowEmoji = '';
    const purpleEmoji = '';

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#e42643')
      .setTitle('Choose your own **Color Role**!')
      .setDescription(
        'Choosing a color role will give you a coloured name!\n\n' +
          `${pinkEmoji} for pink color\n` +
          `${yellowEmoji} for yellow color\n` +
          `${purpleEmoji} for purple color`,
      );

    let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
    messageEmbed.react(pinkEmoji);
    messageEmbed.react(yellowEmoji);
    messageEmbed.react(purpleEmoji);
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! however there is still a little problem i am encountering right now. after executing the command the bot seems to have no issue sending the embed, however it does not load every emoji and returns a error stating: TypeError: Cannot read property 'partial' of undefined at line 3 of the messageReactionAdd.js file.

Comment: Looks like I made a typo `reation.message.partial` should be `reaction.message.partial`.

Comment: i fixed the typo but it still gives me the same error. it seems it has something to do with the .partial itself

Comment: Oh, so it says `reaction.message` is undefined. What if you swap those two lines (line 3 and 4) so it makes sure the reaction is fetched first.

Comment: changing these two sadly didn't make a change it still says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'partial' of undefined"

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening. You should do some basic debugging though. Check the value of `reaction` for example. The code above works for me: https://imgur.com/a/74zWPOU

Comment: i checked the value of reaction which returns a huge list of values, however if i check the value of partial its still giving me a error stating that partial is undefined. i did some research on the internet but i couldn't find anything related to this particular error.